# Configuring CRM with an Exchange Server outside O365 using SSS

Tags: dynamics-crm, exchange-server

I have a requirement where I need to configure my CRM Online with an Exchange Server which is hosted out of my organization's Office 365 to sync Emails for Incoming and Outgoing profiles.

Of the steps, I understand that I need to setup and Email Server Profile of type Exchange that has Server Location pointing to the Exchange Server which I have been using currently. However, I get an error saying that the configuration is invalid and I don't get to save the Incoming and Outgoing server locations. Also, do I need authentication for the same? If yes, of whom should it be? The current Incoming and Outgoing is set to the URL. (Without '/EWS/Exchange.asmx' which is used by default for hosting it on O365.

Any help / links to blogs that effectively explain this would really help.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

[Supported email service configurations for server-side synchronization](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531050.aspx)

CRM Online only supports Server Side Synchronization with:

- Exchange Online in the same tenant in Office365 (mail, tasks, etc.)
- Gmail or Yahoo! Mail via POP3/SMTP (mail only)

Anything else is not (yet<sup>1</sup>) supported.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Online to On-Premise SSS is supposed to become supported at some point in the future</sub>

Comment: Thanks Alex, I get it. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways of handling email processing in CRM:

- Server-side synchronization
- CRM for Outlook
- Email Router

Server-side synchronization does not support hybrid deployments (e.g. CRM Online with Exchange On-premise), as Alex mentions.

I suggest looking into the [Email Router](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn832088.aspx). You install it on a machine which is then responsible for synchronizing email messages between CRM and Exchange. For an in-depth explanaion, see [Email Router Demystified](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dynamicscrmsupportblog/archive/2012/11/09/email-router-demystified-explanation).

If you also need to synchronize Outlook contacts, tasks and appointments have a look at [CRM for Outlook](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn832129.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot Henrik ! :)